# Must Waitrose modify its free coffee machines for Barbara?

Tags: discrimination, any-jurisdiction, equality-act-2010, reasonable-adjustment, disability

Waitrose has a policy of giving one free coffee from an automatic dispensing machine per day to its Waitrose card holders if they make any other purchase using their MyQaitrose card.

Barbara suffers a detriment because she comes in for her daily shopping and loves free coffee but has poor vision so needs to every day wait some 5-10 minutes for someone to attend to her at the customer service desk and ask one of the staff to help her operate the coffee dispensing machine.

This wasted time could be avoided if only the touch screen used a high contrast colour scheme. She requests this under the equality act 2010 as a reasonable adjustment in respect of her disability of impaired vision.

Is Waitrose and Partners required to commission from the automatic coffee dispensing machine’s manufacturer, at its own expense, a new high contrast mode for the sake of Barbara and other poor-vision customers? Why or why not?

Comment: I don't know about the Equality Act, but in the United States, it seems unlikely this would be the required outcome under the ADA. Waitrose needs to make "reasonable accommodations," and diverting staff to personally wait on Barbara seems sufficient to meet that standard.

Comment: By my reading of the equality act (which I accept may be unsophisticated and overly literal/simplistic: I simply do not know what kinds of styles of interpretation have so far judicially prevailed), this may well be inadequate under the equality act, because the purpose and statutory standard for a reasonable adjustment is to enable the disabled to access the service or premises without any disadvantage compared with one who does not possess the disability. In the same way I don’t think that making a customer wait 10 minutes for two or three staff members to be available who may then nonethele

Comment: ss very gladly and kindly carry Whelan in his wheelchair up the stairs would be an adequate substitute for spending the money to simply install a ramp so that he may enter immediately just like anyone else who doesn’t have to wait 10 minutes to enter the store each time they visit.

Comment: Arguably the very ideal of fully equalising the playing field so that disabilities do not cause any disadvantage is inherently unrealistic, idealistic, perhaps such as to be delusional and absurd. But that is nonetheless my reading of the law as it is written. I’m just wondering if I’m missing something about how it should be read.

Comment: I don't think that's actually the standard the law uses. The requirement is not to mitigate "any disadvantage"; instead, it is to address *substantial* disadvantages. I'm not sure personal coffee service counts as a substantial disadvantage compared to self-serve.

Comment: @bdb484 then please consider my edited scenario which circumvents this oversight.